# stereoisomerism and stereoisomers

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Can we have [stereoisomerism](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/105/92) as the synonym of stereoisomers?

In my opinion, stereoisomerism is a concept and stereoisomers are for the molecules.

Most of the times the question will be on the isomers and not on the concept, its better to have the tag on molecules and not on the concept

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably go for a [stereochemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stereochemistry) tag instead, we probably don't need any further subdivisions at the moment.

Comment: I agree. Note: questions just asking for stereoisomers are probably offtopic by our (not yet existant) homework policy.