# Should we merge the stereochemistry and stereoisomerism tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

This seems to be have been sort of raised a while ago but nothing was done about it. [stereoisomerism and stereoisomers](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/stereoisomerism-and-stereoisomers)

Basically I don't see any difference between [stereoisomerism](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stereoisomerism) and [stereochemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stereochemistry) and there are several questions which have both tags which seems redundant.

Should we merge these tags or is there some difference I am not seeing?

Comment: Yes, they look redundant, since stereochemistry is a branch of chemistry which studies stereoisomers.

Comment: I would certainly vote for making stereoisomerism a synonym for [tag:stereochemistry], which seems the more common concept.

Comment: Done; since there already seemed to be agreement on the old thread and there are votes here too.